# Program for HID USB Scale to Transfer Weight to MS Excel

Tags: excel, usb, scale, hid

I need to find a program that can help me transfer the weight on the scale http://global.dymo.com/enUS/Products/10_lb__USB_Mailing_Scale.html onto Microsoft excel. Can someone help me out or point me in the right direction? The scale does signify that the reading has stabilized and I think that is the cue for it to write the weight into the cell in Excel. The scale can read the weight in grams or ounces but I prefer it to be on grams.

Thanks for the help! =)

Comment: Here's some information regarding this scale:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?dc59b02ecc.jpg

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?2916c4a9a9.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need 2 different things,

1. Read the grams information from the USB device (using some tool)
2. Write the data into MS Excel using SQL

Now, reading the data from the USB device will be tricky, if the supplier has not provided the required API ...

Note: In case the supplier did not give you any API, then you are in a soup ~~~